# Copy of a sharepoint list ,with all items

Tags: 2010, 2013, list

How do i make a copy of an entire list with 500000 millions items ? Can anyone provide me a powershell script or workaround ? I tried renaming the list , but the internal name of list doesnt get change ,so that wont solve the purpose .

Comment: did you try to export and import of List?

Comment: Or just get the list with PowerShell, and create a new list with the variable ?

Comment: create a new list with the variable using powershell ? I didnt get this , can you explain more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways to copy the List with all items.But with 500 Millions your options are very limited.

You can Use one of these:

- Export List and Import list with new name
- Use the 3rd party tools i.e ShareGate, MetaLogix.
- Try the code from [technet gallery](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Powershell-script-to-copy-3890a86f)
- another way is Save List as template include content( but i dont think so it will work with tons of item).
- Or create a workflow to copy the list items but again number of items will be issue.

Comment: i considered your option of import and export . After importing i am not see the items in the list ? But i see there are 37 items on the viewlsts.aspx page

Comment: what command you use?

Comment: stsadm -o Import -URL "https://simpsons.com/homer/" -FileName C:\NIKHIL\homerLIST\track.cmp

Comment: how many items in the list when you exported? export import works without issue

Comment: both import/export is success . but there are no items seen.

Comment: I am not sure where things getting wrong...Becuase I did the same thing without any issue...could you please check the export log file & import log file?

Comment: If i use a different site collection , i am able to see the backed up files . But if i use the same site collection for backup , i am seeing any list items